# Using Sidekiq to process reports: How to update the page when a job is completed?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, sidekiq

I would like use Sidekiq to run reports in the background without locking the application. I would also like for the view to show the report page.

It goes something like this (but using Sidekiq):

```
When I go to the Admin/reports page
and I click on the 'View Report'
I see the report
```

And also,

```
When I go to the Admin/reports page
and I click on "Download CSV"
My browser downloads the report in CSV format
```

I know how to queue a job but it is not clear for me how to update the view once it is complete. I understand that this is not the textbook case of using Sidekiq, but can't imagine I am the first person trying to implement this kind of workflow.

I envision letting Admin users wait a few seconds for the report to be prepared and start downloading/start displaying and would like to show them a temporary message while they wait.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking "how do I make an asynchronous process synchronous?"  Answer: by not making it asynchronous.  Don't send it off to Sidekiq.

Comment: Thank you, I am already considering this possibility, along with increasing the number of web processes (Heroku). I would like to see if there are other options. Edit: Considering that you are the author of Sidekiq, I will probably settle for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Per Mike Perham's recommendation I will not try to turn an asynchronous task into a synchronous one. I will monitor performance and if the reports start taking too much resources, I will

- Add a web worker, or
- Email the reports upon completion instead of offering an in-browser download. This will allow me to add them to a background task.

Answer (score 0):

With Sidekiq Pro you can use [Sidekiq Bathces](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) to process data using Sidekiq jobs and make a report upon batch completion .

```
batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
batch.on(:success, SendReportCallback, :to => user.email)
batch.jobs do
  rows.each { |row| RowWorker.perform_async(row) }
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately paying for Sidekick pro is not an option on this project.